# What is the cleanest way of setting proportional sizes of attributes within tkinter widgets and having them scale with the window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

In a Tkinter app, I want to have all of the text in all the widgets to wrap according to the width of the widget, and the column widths in the treeviews to be set to certain predefined proportions of the entire widget width. I want it to update automatically as the window resizes, but keeping the same proportions.

My code below reproduces a minimal part of the user interface for an app I'm trying to develop.

I have come up with a way of automatically resizing the widget attributes with the window size - but they don't start out that way when the app first starts up. I also feel like there must be a more graceful way to just set the proportions and let Tkinter handle the resizing.

When you run the code, you can see that the treeview columns don't immediately resize to the desired proportions, they only resize once the main window is resized. In my case, all columns after the first one should be 1/6th the width of the treeview, and then the first column should take the remaining space.

If you choose a small enough value for `window_size_multiplier`, you can see that the text doesn't immediately start wrapping, but will only start wrapping properly when you resize the window.

I also struggled to get the actual widget.winfo_width inside the **init**.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Main application class
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize window
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        window_size_multiplier = 0.2
        window_width = int(screen_width * window_size_multiplier)
        window_height = int(screen_height * window_size_multiplier)
        x_position = int((screen_width - window_width) / 2)
        y_position = int((screen_height - window_height) / 2)
        self.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

        # Configure grid
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Column for match results display
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)     # Row for buttons and labels

        # Create frame
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)

        # Bind frames to grid
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew", padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create widgets
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Big ol' label with lots of text")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Big momma button with lots of text")
        self.items_display = ttk.Treeview(self.frame, columns=('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'), show='headings')
        self.items_display.heading('Col1', text='Col1')
        self.items_display.heading('Col2', text='Col2')
        self.items_display.heading('Col3', text='Col3')

        # Bind widgets to frame
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.items_display.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)
        
        # Allow the treeview to expand vertically
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)          
        # Don't allow the scrollbar to expand horizontally
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)        
        # Allow all buttons and treviews to expand/contract horizontally together
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Bind UI resizing events
        self.after(100, self.bind_resize_treeview_columns)
        self.after(100, self.bind_resize_text_wraplength)

    def bind_resize_text_wraplength(self):
        for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
            if isinstance(widget, (tk.Label, tk.Button, tk.Radiobutton)):
                widget.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_text_wraplength)

    def resize_text_wraplength(self, event):
        width = event.width + 10 # Widget width plus a little extra
        event.widget.configure(wraplength=width)

    def bind_resize_treeview_columns(self):
        for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
            if isinstance(widget, ttk.Treeview):
                widget.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_treeview_columns)

    def resize_treeview_columns(self, event):
        # All columns after the first one should be 1/6th the width of the treeview, and then the first should take the remaining space.

        # Get the treeview associated with the event that called this function
        treeview = event.widget
        # Get the width of the treeview widget
        treeview_width = treeview.winfo_width()

        # Calculate the width for all columns that come after the first one
        num_columns = len(treeview["columns"])
        secondary_column_width = treeview_width // 6
        first_column_width = treeview_width - (secondary_column_width * (num_columns - 1))

        # Set the first column's width
        treeview.column(treeview["columns"][0], width=first_column_width)

        # Set the other columns' widths
        for col in treeview["columns"][1:]:
            treeview.column(col, minwidth=50, width=secondary_column_width)

# Running the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you want to resize those widgets when the application starts, then why do you use `.after()` to execute `.bind_resize_xxxx()` functions?

Comment: @acw1668 That is what the original code I posted is already doing. However, it doesn't apply the sizes to the the widget attributes as the UI initializes, it only applies once the window gets resized. The solution I posted below seems to fix this and is overall a little more graceful. It calls the resize functions during initialization, as well as binding the functions to the window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have found of doing it is by having functions that set the text wrapping/column sizes, calling it in the **init**, and then also binding them to the window resize event in the **init** as well.

Like so:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        ### Code to initialize UI ###

        # Call resize functions immediately after setup
        self.resize_treeview_columns()
        self.resize_text_wraplength()

        # Bind resizing to window size change
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_window_resize)

    def on_window_resize(self, event):
        # Call resize functions when the window is resized
        self.resize_treeview_columns()
        self.resize_text_wraplength()

    def resize_treeview_columns(self):
        ### code to set treeview column sizes ###

    def resize_text_wraplength(self):
        ### code to set treeview wraplength ###
```

So the whole code would look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Main application class
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize window
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        window_size_multiplier = 0.1
        window_width = int(screen_width * window_size_multiplier)
        window_height = int(screen_height * window_size_multiplier)
        x_position = int((screen_width - window_width) / 2)
        y_position = int((screen_height - window_height) / 2)
        self.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

        # Configure grid
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # Allow column to expand
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

        # Create frame
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)

        # Bind frames to grid
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew", padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create widgets
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Big ol' label with lots of text")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Big momma button with lots of text")
        self.items_display = ttk.Treeview(self.frame, columns=('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'), show='headings')
        self.items_display.heading('Col1', text='Col1')
        self.items_display.heading('Col2', text='Col2')
        self.items_display.heading('Col3', text='Col3')

        # Bind widgets to frame
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.items_display.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)
        
        # Allow the treeview to expand vertically
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)          
        # Don't allow the scrollbar to expand horizontally
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)        
        # Allow all buttons and treviews to expand/contract horizontally together
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Call resize functions immediately after setup
        self.resize_treeview_columns_initial()
        self.resize_text_wraplength_initial()

        # Bind resizing to window size change
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_window_resize)

    def on_window_resize(self, event):
        # Call resize functions when the window is resized
        self.resize_treeview_columns_initial()
        self.resize_text_wraplength_initial()

    def resize_treeview_columns_initial(self):
        # Initial resize of treeview columns
        treeview = self.items_display
        treeview_width = treeview.winfo_width()
        num_columns = len(treeview["columns"])
        secondary_column_width = treeview_width // 6
        first_column_width = treeview_width - (secondary_column_width * (num_columns - 1))
        treeview.column(treeview["columns"][0], width=first_column_width)
        for col in treeview["columns"][1:]:
            treeview.column(col, minwidth=50, width=secondary_column_width)

    def resize_text_wraplength_initial(self):
        # Initial resize of text wraplength
        for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
            if isinstance(widget, (tk.Label, tk.Button, tk.Radiobutton)):
                width = widget.winfo_width() + 10
                widget.configure(wraplength=width)

# Running the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

What do y'all think?